# Mongoose schema array with extra ids

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose schema for a node js app I'm working on:

```
var memory = new schema({
    date_added: Date,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    personsInvolved: [{person: String}],
    location: String,
    uniqueness: Number,
    category: String
});
```

It has an array field called personsInvolved that just has one field in it, person.

In my app, there's a form that takes a list of people, separated by a comma and it goes to a create function that takes that value and splits it on the commas into an array.

That part works, but it adds an _id field to each person in the array when I save the document into mongo. It looks like this:

```
personsInvolved:
   [ { person: 'Test', _id: 52c6d6c2457e5ce02b00000b },
     { person: ' test2', _id: 52c6d6c2457e5ce02b00000c },
     { person: ' test3', _id: 52c6d6c2457e5ce02b00000d } ] }
```

Is there a way to make it so the _id field doesn't get added to each person? This is the code I'm using to save the record to mongo:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    // people are separated by a comma
    var people = req.body.people;
    var peopleArr = req.body.people.split(",");

    var newMem = new memory();
    newMem.date_added = Date.now();
    newMem.name = req.body.name;
    newMem.description = req.body.description;
    for(var i in peopleArr) {
        var name = {person: peopleArr[i]};
        newMem.personsInvolved.push(name);
    }
    newMem.location = req.body.location;
    newMem.uniqueness = req.body.uniqueness;
    newMem.category = req.body.category;
    console.log(newMem);
    newMem.save(function(err, memory, count) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

I'm only using personsInvolved as data, the persons in the array are not being used to identify with any other documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make person a real schema model (as opposed to an anonymous object) and pass it `{_id:false}`.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html